# MYSQL - How can i check if there is one possible combination of value that fits a range

Tags: mysql, combinations

I am trying to run an algorithm to include / exclude a number of appartments depending if there is a total amount of square meters to fit a criteria.

Here's an example with a set of data :

```
CREATE TABLE lot
( `id` int(11), `surface_dispo` int(11));


INSERT INTO lot
    (`id`, `surface_dispo`)
VALUES
    ('1', '550'),
    ('2', '700'),
    ('3', '850');
```

Let's say that I want to find every possible combination that would fit between 1500 and 2000 square meters. In that example I should be able to retrieve the combination of lot N° 2 and 3, but not 1 2 and 3

I have read some topics about recursive fonctions in MYSQL but I couldn't get to convert examples I found because they were too specifically about string concatenation, and not SUM.

Please also note that the SUM of those lots could be with N numbers involved, let's say that i want to find all of the available surfaces between 2000 AND 2500, I should retrieve 1 + 2 + 3.

Thank you in advance for your help, I will provide any further information needed.

Comment: you should show us what you tried so far

Comment: This sounds like a variant of the Knapsack problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem - as N becomes larger this becomes computationally very intensive.  Can you put some boundaries on N?  Say, a maximum of 5?

Comment: @RobEyre No, this is more simple, one-dimentional cutting-stock problem.

Comment: @RobEyre Unfortunately no, i cannot limit N. What i am looking for now, based on the accepted answer, is a way to make the recursive function stop iterating as soon as it finds a possible match, because i only need one possible combination to fit between min and max for my statement to be true, so i don't need to iterate over ALL of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution (a sample):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  val INT
);
INSERT INTO test (val)
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT 1 num UNION ALL SELECT num + 1 FROM cte LIMIT 10
)
SELECT 1000 * RAND() FROM cte;
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 745 |
| 2 | 992 |
| 3 | 726 |
| 4 | 651 |
| 5 | 80 |
| 6 | 445 |
| 7 | 985 |
| 8 | 590 |
| 9 | 995 |
| 10 | 203 |

```
SET @minimal := 2000;
set @maximal := 2100;
```

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT id, val AS total, CAST(id AS CHAR(65535)) rowset FROM test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT test.id, cte.total + test.val, CONCAT_WS(',', cte.rowset, test.id)
  FROM cte
  JOIN test ON test.id > cte.id AND cte.total < @maximal
)
SELECT rowset, total
FROM cte
WHERE total BETWEEN @minimal AND @maximal;
```

| rowset | total |
| --- | --- |
| 1,3,8 | 2061 |
| 2,4,6 | 2088 |
| 2,5,7 | 2057 |
| 2,5,9 | 2067 |
| 2,6,8 | 2027 |
| 4,6,7 | 2081 |
| 4,6,9 | 2091 |
| 5,7,9 | 2060 |
| 6,7,8 | 2020 |
| 6,8,9 | 2030 |
| 1,2,5,10 | 2020 |
| 1,4,5,8 | 2066 |
| 1,4,6,10 | 2044 |
| 1,5,7,10 | 2013 |
| 1,5,9,10 | 2023 |
| 2,3,5,10 | 2001 |
| 3,4,5,8 | 2047 |
| 3,4,6,10 | 2025 |
| 3,5,9,10 | 2004 |
| 5,6,7,8 | 2100 |
| 1,5,6,8,10 | 2063 |
| 3,5,6,8,10 | 2044 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SUvHX_2G)

Comment: I spend a good hour tweaking your answer but it ended up working perfectly, and for that, thank you very much. Now my only issue left is performance, recursvie requests are quite demanding, and I end up timing out. Could there be a way to tell the recursive fonction to stop iterating as soon as it matches a combination that fits between minimal and maximal ?

Comment: @Nico You may add a flag based on user-defined variable which breaks the iterations if any solution is found. See https://dbfiddle.uk/zhj0CRCB Of course you cannot predict what solution will be found from all possible ones, the only guarantee is that the amount of elements in the solution will be the least possible. In my sample it decreases the amount of iterations from 5 to 3.